# tkinter - bind ALL 'chosen' events of a widget to a callback

Tags: tkinter

I'm quite new to tkinter.
I have a GUI application, with Radiobuttons, among other widgets.
My main module, the controller (in a loose MVC design), manipulates my view, according to UI events (disable this Entry, enable another, etc.).
Within the init of the controller, after creating the view, I used the **bind()** function to connect  event to my ThisOrThatRadioButton(...) callback function. It works... with the mouse.
Playing with the application, I see I can navigate to the Radiobutton with the keyboard (tabs) and choose the button (space), but, then - the callback isn't called.
**How can I bind the whole 'chosen' event to the callback?**
Or must I bind a few (or many) different events to the same callback?
Thanks

edit:
I bind using the widget's **bind()** function, not the **command=MyCallback**, because I want the widget to call a function of the **controller class**, not of the view class:

```
self.view.parentFrame.myRadioB.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.ControllerCallback)
```

The widget is part of the View class, so it doesn't know (and shouldn't know) of the controller callback, I think.
I'm new to Python, my point-of-view is of a more generic software-design, so maybe I'm missing some obvious stuff.

Comment: you can have the event or the command call any function you like, the difference is that `bind` callbacks pass an event and `command` callbacks dont, are you using the event for anything?

Comment: I'm currently not using the events, just the simple 'chosen' event. The issue is that I don't want the View module to have knowledge of the 'logic' of the app', thus the controller binds the callback. I don't want View to have "import MyController"

Answer (score 2):

you haven't stated what method you are using to bind (but i'm guessing you bind a mouse event) instead you can add a `command` to the constructor of each button, then anything that changes the selection (mouse or keyboard) will call your callback, albeit without the `event` object:

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm

```
from tkinter import *

def changed():
    print("Changed value")
master = Tk()

v = IntVar()

Radiobutton(master, text="One", variable=v, value=1, command=changed).pack(anchor=W)
Radiobutton(master, text="Two", variable=v, value=2, command=changed).pack(anchor=W)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question (and formatted it, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, thanks to James Kent, who made me think:
My controller module, instead of **binding** a specific event, sets the command via **widget.configure()**.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68524/1499700