# Refreshing buttons in Tkinter with new command

Tags: python, tkinter

So basically I am trying to make a GUI to print multiple pdfs easily and without having to open them (labels for food products).

In column one you select the language, and in column two you select the label which is then printed in the selected language.

I've spent about two hours googling the problem, and I found the var = StringVar() solution for the button text, and this solution: [Change command Method for Tkinter Button in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68327/change-command-method-for-tkinter-button-in-python)

Unfortunately it doesn't work in my case, since I am creating the buttons by looping through a for function - and because of that I can't select them with the x.configure() function.

About the code, my approach so far was to make the language buttons by looping through a dictionary with all the languages I need. By pressing a button ("United Kingdom") the language (here the variable "sprache") is set to the two-letter code of the language, i.e. "en". 
Pressing the "Shiro Shoyu" button (which is created by looping through the products dictionary) in the second column then sends a command to print shiroshoyu_en.pdf

```py
master = Tk()


#Printing function
def label(x, y):
    file = "%s_%s.pdf" % (x, y)
    win32api.ShellExecute(0, 'open', GSPRINT_PATH, '-ghostscript "'+GHOSTSCRIPT_PATH+'" -printer "'+currentprinter+'" "'+file+'"', '.', 0)

def activelanguage(x):
    global sprache
    sprache = x
    print("Sprache auf %s geändert" % x)

sprache = 'de'

#Buttons to select the language

g = 1
for key, value in languages.items():
    b = Button(master, text="%s" % value, command=partial(activelanguage, key), anchor="w")
    b.grid(row=g, column=1)
    g = g +1

#Product buttons
f = 1
for key, value in products.items():
    b = Button(master, text="%s" % value, command=partial(label,key,sprache), anchor="w")
    b.grid(row=f, column=2)
    f = f +1


#####
master.configure(background='white')
master.mainloop()
```

The problem is, the buttons in the second column need a refresh, because I may press on "Spain" to set "sprache" to "es", but the buttons in the second column are still set to "en".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference buttons created in a loop by saving them in a list or dictionary.

For example:

```
buttons = {}
for key, value in products.items():
    b = Button(...)
    buttons[(key, value)] = b
    ...
```

and later:

```
for key, value in products.items():
    buttons[(key, value)].configure(...)
```