# A better way to do this in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently writing a Python Tkinter START and STOP button.

As it uses `tkinter` when I click START the STOP button should appear in it's place. But to do this I need to use `.destroy()` on the button. So to get around this I've done the following (see code blow); however it seems bulky and can't but feel I've over complicated it. Any suggestions would be great

```
    def stop():
        global start_button

        try:
            stop_button.destroy()
        except NameError:
            pass

        print("Stopped. Hit GO to go again!")
        start_button = Button(self.b, text="GO!", font="calibri, 18", command=started, fg="white", width=10)
        start_button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        start_button.config(bg="green")

    def started():
        global stop_button

        try:
            start_button.destroy()
        except NameError:
            pass

        print("Started. Hit ENTER to Stop!")
        stop_button = Button(self.b, text="STOP!", font="calibri, 18", command=stop, fg="white", width=10)
        stop_button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        stop_button.config(bg="red")

    def first_start():
        start.destroy()
        started()

    start = Button(self.b, text="START!", font="calibri, 18", command=first_start, fg="white", width=10)
    start.pack(side=BOTTOM)
    start.config(bg="green")
```

Comment: Why don't you keep the Button, but change the name and command?

Comment: How would i do that?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68327/change-command-method-for-tkinter-button-in-python) is a question with a very similar topic. Basically, you use the `configure` method as you already do, but also configure name and command with it. I will mark this as a duplicate

Comment: Why don't you just change the attributes (e.g. text, bg, etc) of the button instead using `configure()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change command Method for Tkinter Button in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68327/change-command-method-for-tkinter-button-in-python)

Comment: Hi partially. Due to the button needing to be destroyed this does not solve it

Comment: Why should the Button be destroyed?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a minimalist start/stop button that toggles its aspect and behavior when clicked. There is no need to destroy and replace buttons with such a toggling mechanism.

```
import tkinter as tk


def do_the_start_things():
    # replace print with the things to do at start
    print('starting now')
    
def do_the_stop_things():
    # replace print with the things to do at stop
    print('stopped!')

def toggle_start_stop():
    if startstop['text'] == 'START':
        startstop.config(text='STOP', fg='red')
        do_the_start_things()
    else:
        startstop.config(text='START', fg='green')
        do_the_stop_things()

        
root = tk.Tk()
startstop = tk.Button(root, text='START', command=toggle_start_stop, fg='green')
startstop.pack()


root.mainloop()
```